# Why methods of my Iterator cant be resolved?

Tags: java, list, collections, iterator, iterable

I'm doing kind of a 'decorator' to List Collection in Java. Sth is wrong and i have no idea what it is. Here is my code and observed error.

***1. myListContainer.java***

```
public class myListContainer<T> implements List<T>{
    List<T> basicList;

    public myListContainer(List<T> basicList) {
        this.basicList = basicList;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {         
        return new myIterator();
    }
    private class myIterator implements Iterator<T>{
        int actIndex;
        int visitTwice;

        public myIterator() {
            this.actIndex = 0;
            this.visitTwice = 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (actIndex < basicList.size() - 1)
                return true;
            else if (actIndex == basicList.size() - 1 &&visitTwice < 1)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            if (this.hasNext()) {
                 if (visitTwice < 1) {
                     visitTwice = 1;
                     return basicList.get(actIndex);
                } else {
                    visitTwice = 0;
                    return basicList.get(actIndex++);
                }
            }
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }

    //implementation of methods form List<T> interface

}
```

***2. Client.java*** (psvm) ***AND A PROBLEM***

```
public class Client {
    List<String> test = new myListContainer<>(Arrays.asList("Janek", 
              "Bartek", "Stefan", "Horacy", "Jakub", "Antoni"));

    boolean bl = test.iterator().hasNext();  //ok, 
    Iterator iter = test.iterator();
    iter.hasNext();                    //not ok, cannot resolve hasNext
}
```

***PROBLEM:***

***1. test.iterator().hasNext() WORKS Fine***

***2. iter.hasNext() DOESN'T WORK, it is not visible(hasNext), 'Cannot resolve symbol'***

EDIT: Certainly all files are in one module, and has necessary imports.

Comment: Do not call your iterator `Iterator` ... that's just asking for trouble.  Name it something else, such as `MyIterator<T>`, and where you declare the (incorrectly named) `myIterator`, call that `MyIteratorImpl`.  Once you resolve the name conflict you can begin to address the other problems in your code.

Comment: Thx, yeah that name conflict was terrible. But still, problem exists.

Comment: If you want help, please update all the code in your question to its current state, with the name conflict resolved.  Otherwise you will waste people's time.

Comment: Ok, sa i deleted interface MyIterator, it was unnecesery in this context, now it should be cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the scope of the call, in this scope of the class you should initialize or declare members/instance-variables.
This is works -  `boolean bl = test.iterator().hasNext();  //ok, 
    Iterator iter = test.iterator();` because it's a declarations of a class members.

So if yo'll try to call `hasNext()` in function scope- it will work. see example:

```
public class Client {
    List<String> test = new myListContainer<>(Arrays.asList("Janek",
        "Bartek", "Stefan", "Horacy", "Jakub", "Antoni"));

    boolean bl = test.iterator().hasNext();  //ok, 
    Iterator iter = test.iterator();

    public void foo() {
        while (iter.hasNext()) { // here it will work!

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very sorry, accidentally i deleted my main function and it was a problem. Sorry again.

QUESTION COULD BE DELETED, its just my simple mistake, sorry.